# Mongo NoSuchMethodError insertOne when deployed to AWS with SpringBoot

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, maven

My DAO works fine when running locally, allowing DB insert however when deployed to Beanstalk, the follow exception occurs.

I cannot reproduce this locally, even by deleting all Mongo dependencies in m2 repo. I've tried different Mongo versions as well as allowing Spring to manage Mongo deps.

**module POM**

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

**Parent POM**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
```

**stack trace**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.insertOne(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/mongodb/client/result/InsertOneResult;
at com.project.data.nosql.dao.SearchRecordMongoDao.insert(SearchRecordMongoDao.java:53) ~[data-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.project.data.nosql.dao.SearchRecordMongoDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$75e83eda.invoke(<generated>) ~[data-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at com.project.data.nosql.dao.SearchRecordMongoDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c4dd29e8.insert(<generated>) ~[data-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.project.async.AsyncSaveSearch.saveReports(AsyncSaveSearch.java:26) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.project.async.AsyncSaveSearch$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a06fec91.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-aop-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_265]
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading `spring-boot-start-parent` to v2.4.0 corrected the issue. This results in mongo driver 4.1.1 managed version.

Oddly, I had to upload this artifact twice to Beanstalk. The first attempt resulted SpringBoot unable to start due to classpath issues. It would start locally so I tried again and now everything works.